# Fix "Lexical or Preprocessor Issue - Extension used" warning in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've inherited a new project, which has several retain cycle warnings caused by implicitly retaining self within various blocks.

In attempting to fix these, I've written

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
```

to create a weak reference for use within the block.

However, Xcode v. 5.1.1 is giving the cryptic warning

```
Lexical or Preprocessor Issue 
Extension used
```

I'm at a loss here-- what does this mean and how can I get rid of it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You get this warning for the use of `typeof` if "Pedantic Warnings" are enabled in the build settings.
From the "Quick Help" for this setting:

> Description   Issue all the warnings demanded by strict ISO C and ISO
>   C++; reject all programs that use forbidden extensions, and some other
>   programs that do not follow ISO C and ISO C++.  For ISO C, follows the
>   version of the ISO C standard specified by any -std option used. 
>   [GCC_WARN_PEDANTIC, -pedantic]

I am not an expert in (ISO) C standards, but according to 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html:

> If you are writing a header file that must work when included in ISO C
>   programs, write `__typeof__` instead of `typeof`. See Alternate Keywords.

and http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html:

> The parser recognizes “`asm`” and “`typeof`” as keywords in gnu* modes;
>   the variants “`__asm__`” and “`__typeof__`” are recognized in all modes.

you can use `__typeof__` instead
if you don't want to disable the warning:

```
__weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
```

Comment: Under `Apple LLVM 5.1 - Warning Policies`, the setting for `Pedantic Warnings` is `NO`. Is there somewhere else this could be enabled?

Comment: Are custom flags set, e.g. "-Weverything" ?

Comment: That's what it was! Thanks Martin!

Answer (score 0):

You can switch off CLANG-Warnings by using -Wno Parameters, specially for this "extension used" Warning it is

-Wno-language-extension-token

cheers